# Why can the pion decay into two photons?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, pions

The neutral pion belongs to the pseudoscalar meson octet, so it has, in the ground state ($L=0$):

\begin{align}
P_{\pi^0}&=-1 \\
C_{\pi^0}&=+1.
\end{align}

And the photon has

\begin{align}
P_\gamma = -1 \\
C_\gamma=-1.
\end{align}

Therefore, since electromagnetic interactions conserve parity and charge conjugation, why does the process

\begin{equation}
\pi^0 \rightarrow \gamma\gamma
\end{equation}
occur? Doesn't it violate parity?

In the example I have seen in class, $C$ conservation is used to explain why the $\pi^0$ cannot decay into three photons, since for $\pi^0 \rightarrow \gamma\gamma\gamma$ we have

\begin{equation}
C_i = +1 \neq C_f = (-1)^3 = -1
\end{equation}

and, for $\pi^0 \rightarrow \gamma\gamma$,

\begin{equation}
C_i = +1 = C_f = (-1)^2 = +1,
\end{equation}
so regarding $C$ conservation it should be allowed. But, considering P conservation,

\begin{align}
\pi^0 \rightarrow \gamma\gamma \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad P_i = (-1)^{L}\times \underbrace{(-1)}_{\text{intrinsic parity}} = -1 \neq P_f = (-1)^2 = +1
\end{align}
so it would be forbidden for $L=0$. And, with the same argument, the decay into three photons would be allowed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The photons have intrinsic spin (or, better, helicity) one, so the pair can have odd  *orbital* angular momentum, still conserving *total* angular momentum (which has to be zero, as the pion is spinless).

Specifically, the spins of the two photon can combine to give total spin $S=1$. This, conmbined with an angular momentum $L=1$, has a $J=0$ component which permits the pion to decay into two photons. You can check from the Clebsch-Gordan table that the final two photon wavefunction is symmetric under particle permutation, as required by Bose statistics.