Question about conservation of total angular momentum in pion decay
I've been reading on conservation laws in particle decays, specifically total angular momentum. I stumbled on two other questions about the decay of a pion to two photons and why it's allowed. In one, they describe why the orbital angular momentum must be 1 to conserve parity, however one describes that "the spins of the two photon can combine to give total spin $S=1$".
This is what confuses me, from what I understood the helicities of the photon can only be $1$ or $-1$ as they are massless, would this not mean that the two photon system can only have total spin $2$ or $0?$ Or am I misinterpreting something?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/450460/365109
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/638818/365109

Two back to back photons may have spin one. Work it out.

This has stumped me before, but my Clebsch-Gordan table says for $s_1=s_2=1$:
$$|S=1, S_z=0\rangle = 
\sqrt{\frac 1 2}\Big(
|+-\rangle - |-+\rangle
\Big)
$$
($+-$ refers to helicity, $S, s_i$ are total and individual spins, respectively).
Not sure why I was confused before...
Combing $S=1$ and $L=1$ ($|S_z, M\rangle$) in to $|J, J_z\rangle = |0, 0\rangle$ proceeds as:
$$|J=0, J_z=0\rangle=
\sqrt{\frac 1 3}
\Big(
|1, -1\rangle -
|0, 0\rangle +
|-1, 1\rangle
\Big)
$$

Thanks for your response, I see now how you arrive at the top answer. I am a little confused by the last section though, I assume from the top line that the only spin 1 state a two photon system can have is with $S_{z} = 0$, but your last line suggests that the pion state is a linear combination with states of $S_{z} = 1, 0, -1$?

@Blazeboy01 Yes, that's exactly why it's confusing unless you practice reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients . Usually I include them, but my screen shot isn't working. The photons are for total spin $S=1$, while the pion is for total spin+orbital angular momentum $J=0$, so they are different, though $J_z=S_z=0$.

I have a feeling I didn't clearly word what my original intention was with the reply.  It seems that for the two photon state the only possible combination with total $S=1$ is the one you showed, as all others involve combinations of the individual photons possessing $S_{z}=0$ (helicity) which isn't possible for a massless particle. What I was trying to ask was that in the final state combining both the $S=1$ and $L=1$ to form the $J=0$ pion state, it contains combinations of $S_{z}=-1,1$ for the two photon state, but I was under the assumption the only allowed $S=1$ state had $S_{z}=0$?

@Blazeboy01 yeah, I'm confused, again. I think you're right. I have some software that computes this stuff that I'll try later.
